# How do I reference a C# keyword in XML documentation?

Tags: c#, keyword, xml-documentation

`<see cref="switch" />`, for example, doesn't work - I get the compilation warning: `XML comment on ... has syntactically incorrect cref attribute 'switch'`

---

Context for those who are interested...

```
/// <summary>Provides base functionality for hand-coded abstractions of API method wrappers, mostly those that abstract over
/// parameters that are required to be JSON-encoded.</summary>
public class FacebookArgs : Dictionary<String, Object>
{
    /// <summary>Initializes an instance of <see cref="FacebookArgs" />.</summary>
    public FacebookArgs() { }

    /// <summary>Intializes an instance of <see cref="FacebookArgs" />, that contains elements copied from <paramref name="dictionary "/>.</summary>
    /// <param name="dictionary"></param>
    public FacebookArgs(IDictionary<String, Object> dictionary)
        : base(dictionary) { }

    /// <summary>Gets or sets the value associated with the specified key.</summary>
    /// <param name="key">The key of the value to get or set.</param>
    /// <returns>The value associated with the specified key.</returns>
    /// <remarks>This implementation hides the base indexer implementation such that specifying a key that does not exist returns null rather than throwing a <see cref="KeyNotFoundException" />.</remarks>
    public new Object this[String key]
    {
        get
        {
            Object value;
            if (this.TryGetValue(key, out value)) return value;
            else return null;
        }
        set { base[key] = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>In derived classes, provides specialized serialization logic for specific properties contained in this object.</summary>
    /// <param name="key">The key of the property to serialize.</param>
    /// <param name="args">A reference to a dictionary of arguments that will be passed directly to a <see cref="FacebookRequest" /> object.</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// <para>This method allows specialized serialization logic, such as JSON encoding, to be applied to specific properties.</para>
    /// <para>To implement, use a <c>switch</c> (<c>Select</c> in VB.NET) statement to filter based on <paramref name="key" /> and provide the property-specific logic.
    /// The resulting value should then be added to <paramref name="args" /> using the same <paramref name="key "/>.
    /// </para>
    /// <para>Properties that do not require additional processing (strings, integral values, etc) should be ignored.</para>
    /// </remarks>
    protected virtual void SerializeProperty(String key, ref IDictionary<String, Object> args) { }

    /// <summary>Returns a dictionary of key/value pairs suitable to be passed a <see cref="FacebookRequest" /> object.</summary>
    /// <returns>A dictionary of key/value pairs suitable to be passed a <see cref="FacebookRequest" /> object.</returns>
    /// <remarks>This method calls the <see cref="SerializeProperty" /> for each key in the object, which allows property-specific processing
    /// to be done on any property.</remarks>
    /// <seealso cref="SerializeProperty" />
    public IDictionary<String, Object> GetArgs()
    {
        IDictionary<String, Object> args = new Dictionary<String, Object>();

        foreach (String key in this.Keys)
        {
            this.SerializeProperty(key, ref args);

            if (!args.ContainsKey(key) && this[key] != null)
            {
                args.Add(key, this[key]);
            }
        }

        return args;
    }
}
```

---

The tag in question can be found in the `<remarks>` tag for `SerializeProperty`. I'm erring on the side of verbose documentation. I also plan on providing some `<example>`s, I just haven't gotten around to it yet.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

cref is meant to refer to another member - a class, a method etc.

What would you expect it to link to in this case? In general, what do you want the overall effect to be?

According to this [excellent XML doc guide](http://web.archive.org/web/20080623060531/http://thoughtpad.net/alan-dean/cs-xml-documentation.html), the `<see>` tag has an undocumented attribute `langword`:

```
<see langword="switch" />
```

Would that help you? It might be worth trying it just to see what it does.

If you just want to use a normal hyperlink, use href instead of cref:

```
<see href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx">switch</see>
```

Comment: It even works for VB.NET within a C# project! To implement, use a <see langword="switch" /> (<see langword="Select" /> in VB.NET)

Comment: I have to admit, I'd never seen that attribute before. I just knew of the page, and saw what it had to say for itself :)

Comment: I guess `<see>...</a>` is a typo. Both, `<see href="link"></see>` and `<a href="link"></a>` work for normal hyperlinks (tested with Sandcastle: [SHFB](https://shfb.codeplex.com/)).

Comment: @fedab Or `<see href="link"/>` for short

Comment: Hi from the future when Microsoft [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/recommended-tags#see) `<see langword="..."/>`

Comment: It's a nice touch that you get colored keywords in your IntelliSense documentary. Too bad it's not automatically translated between languages (e.g. when you have <see langword="null"/> defined in a C# project, you will still see "null" if you reference that project in a VB project, instead of "Nothing"), but maybe someday...